# Gradle configuration provided Dependency Ignored in Subproject Build

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I have a project with 1 subproject:

```
projroot/
    settings.gradle
    build.gradle
    mod1/
        build.gradle
```

In `mod1/build.gradle` there is   a "provided" dependency:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
configurations {
    provided
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    provided group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.1.0'
}
```

This doesn't seem to work when `mod1/src/main/java/One.java` imports `javax.servlet.ServletContext`:

```
> Task :mod1:compileJava FAILED
/home/x/groot/mod1/src/main/java/One.java:1: error: package javax.servlet does not exist
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
                    ^
1 error

...
BUILD FAILED in 0s
2 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 1 up-to-date
```

Using gradle-4.4.1.

Am I defining the dependency in an incorrect place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Gradle 2.12 introduced `compileOnly` dependencies I rather recommend to use this. Especially when it comes to a Servlet API that will be provided by the servlet container once you deploy your web application on e.g. Tomcat, JBoss, ....

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.1.0'
}
```

`provided` is a scope used in Maven project that haven't found place in Gradle so far. But `compileOnly` is very close to Mavens `provided` scope.